# Select rows as columns with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have this situation, I have a table with name->value columns like this

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| ip | 12.12.12.12 |
| name | Smith |
| db | base |
| pass | 22222 |

I would like to select this table like this

| ip | name | db | pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.12.121.2 | Smith | base | 22222 |

As if the values of column NAME are the column names and the values of the VALUE column are the column values. And the rows are variable, they can be 2 or 22 so if 22 then there should be 22 columns, well each one has a unique name.

---

I see that crosstab is the solution, so i try this:

select * from crosstab(
'SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM settings'
) as res (section varchar,naam varchar,value1 text);

But i get  ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible.
What is wrong with this query?